# Get image data from camera app immediately after a shot

Tags: android

Is there a way you can get a picture from camera app without asking the user to save or not? Below method works, but if user doesn't save the photo after taking it, the image data is not precessed. Is there a way you can get rid of this "save" or "cancel" process and get the image immediately after the shot for processing in your app?

```
//camera buttton pressed
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent (android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,Take_A_Picture);

//getData from camera app
@Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
  {
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
            if(data == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            else if (requestCode ==Take_A_Picture)
            {
                Uri imageFileUri = data.getData();              
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are hundreds of camera apps that might fulfil the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` request, depending upon what device the user has and what other apps the user installed. What any of them do for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is up to their developers, not you. Some might ask for confirmation. Some might not. You have no way to force other developers to rewrite their apps to offer you control over this, short of taking hostages.

Note: taking hostages may be illegal in some jurisdictions.

Comment: @Nabin: You are welcome to use `android.hardware.Camera` directly and take pictures yourself. If you delegate that responsibility to a third-party app, **the third-party app can do what it wants**.

Comment: i suppose question is:"If I can use customized camera function" :-)

Comment: I think the whoever made the camera apps in android should make this possible for developers.